# How to update vite 3 project to vite 4?

Tags: vite

I have a vite 3 project. How can I update it to vite 4? Do I need to make a new project from scratch and copy the files? Or do I simply update the version number in package.json, delete node_modules folder and do npm install?

https://vitejs.dev/blog/announcing-vite4.html

Answer (score 1):

They didn't announce any breaking changes so I think you can just upgrade to 4 in packages.json...
I'm gonna try it too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to figure this out is to look at the source code of the npm create template they have.

For example, looking at the vue-ts one from https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/create-vite/template-vue-ts/package.json you can see the following package file, and then just use that as a guide:

```js
{
  "name": "vite-vue-typescript-starter",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.45"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0-beta.1",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.24"
  }
}
```